# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):
    news = {}
    # iterate child elements of item
    for child in item:
        # special checking for namespace object content:media
        if child.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}content':
            news['media'] = child.attrib['url']
        else:
            news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')
    newsitems.append(news)
```

whats the problem ?? how am i gonna solve this problem?

Comment: that's because `child.text` is `None`. Filter it out. `if child.text: ...`

Answer (score 3):

here:

```
    else:
        news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')
```

`child.text` is `None` in some cases. So don't create the dict entry in that case, for instance like this:

```
    elif child.text is not None:
        news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')
```